# CSS Moving footer to left align

Tags: css

I am trying to move my footnotes to the very left of the page instead of the default block indentation, but am not having success. Here is the relevant code:

```
.footnote {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  display: none;
  display: footnote;
  display: prince-footnote;
  position: footnote;
  counter-increment: footnote;
  footnote-style-position: inside;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-indent: -10px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: left; }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is the html you are using? Post that please

Comment: Please post also the html, but I can already tell the 'display : none' is useless here

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you create a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ in which we can see your html, css, javascript or whatever you have on it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have used a display element that is redundant, also try floating the element to the left.

```
float:left;
```

if this doesn't work, please post the html so we can see what your dealing with:)